# Office365 authentication without login redirection

Tags: authentication, office365, azure-active-directory, office365api, office365-apps

I'm trying to load data from Office365 email without need for user interaction. I've created Azure App and I have Client ID and Client secret. 
I also have user information (email + password).

I need to call Office365 API to download emails from mailbox. But I need application to download them in background without user interaction (redirecting to MS/Office365 login page) to get authenticated/logged into mailbox.

Is there any way how to do this only through Office API, without need of redirection?

Thanks for any info.

Comment: Yes, you can do thru ADAL lib with UserCredential workflow, but you need to be more specific what have you tried and problem you got with your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are able to create a daemon service app using the **Client Credential flow** to authenticate the app.

Here is a code sample to retrieve the mails using Microsoft Graph SDK with this flow:

```
string clientId = "";
string clientsecret = "";
string tenant = "";
string resourceURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant + "/oauth2/token";
string userMail = "user1@yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com";

var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientsecret);
AuthenticationContext authContext =new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceURL, credential);
var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
   (requestMessage) =>
   {
       requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authResult.AccessToken);

       return Task.FromResult(0);
   }));

var items = await graphserviceClient.Users[userMail].Messages.Request().OrderBy("receivedDateTime desc").GetAsync();

foreach (var item in items)
{
        Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
}
```

And we need to register the app on the Azure AD portal and grant the app **Mail.Read** scope like figure below:
[image]

Refer to [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only) for more detail about calling Microsoft Graph in a service or daemon app

Comment: Thank you, you're right. With that code and  clientId, clientSecret and tenantId data I was able to authenticate my Office365 App. However I'm not shure if I allow "Read mail in all mailboxes" permission for my App if this will mean that I'll be able to access anyone mails(which is huge security risk)? I would need something like: "Read those mailboxes: ...". Anyway thank you for your solution, you're awesome as hell :)

Comment: There is no need to limit the app to access specific mails because the app you **client credential** should be confident. You can just publish the service as you want in your app. I also explain it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397981/restrict-office365-app-read-mail-in-all-mailboxes-permission-to-specific-mailb)