# How to get auth code using office 365 api only?

Tags: xcode, authentication, oauth-2.0, office365, postman

My goal is to get the user's (Office 365 and Outlook.com) mails in a mule project. I am trying to follow the steps described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started 
After registering the app the next step would be to authenticate the user using OAuth2. But I am not able to get the auth code.

Whenever I hit
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/authorize?client_id=clientId&response_mode=query&response_type=code&scope=openid+Mail.Read
in postman, I am getting the sign in html in response.

How do I pass the username and password so that I dont get the signin page in response?

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please check below link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371147/office365-authentication-without-login-redirection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer. Follow the steps mentioned in:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service

and resource = https://graph.microsoft.com